# How to get Audio embeddings using Hubert model

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, nlp

Example code

```
import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor, HubertForCTC
from datasets import load_dataset

processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/hubert-large-ls960-ft")
model = HubertForCTC.from_pretrained("facebook/hubert-large-ls960-ft")
input_values = processor('array from audio file., return_tensors="pt").input_values
```

How to get embeddings after this? There is no last hidden state in the model.

Tried code block I mentioned. Also, tried to create model without last layer and then gave it to input. Another question i have is, say i have clips with different time dimensions then how can i create fixed embeddings? Is mean along the time axis ok or different approach is needed.